# Change symfony date type input display format

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Hi I am using Symfony Date-Type with widget single_text. This is my code.

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
// ...

$builder->add('date_created', DateType::class, [
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    // this is actually the default format for single_text
    'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
]);
```

And I'm getting this output.

[image]

But I need to display it as **mm/dd/yyyy**. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options:

- use html5 (your current setting). In this case documentation says "If you want your field to be rendered as an HTML5 "date" field, you have to use a single_text widget with the yyyy-MM-dd format...". Actually browser shows you html5 widget with 30/12/2019 value but sends 2019-12-30 on submit. Check yourself: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_date
- not use html5:

```php
$builder->add('date_created', DateType::class, [
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'html5' => false,
    'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
]);
```

You will be able to set and submit date in `yyyy-MM-dd` format.